# How can I retrieve (and conditionally act on) the language of my document?

Tags: conditionals, babel, languages, polyglossia

I have a collection of documents that share a common style file that has all the functions and templating shared by this particular collection. The majority of these are all in the same language, but o handful of them are actually translations of the others. I would like to keep using the same style include file, but a few tidbits (for example in the footer and title sheet) need to be adjusted per-language.

I'm using [polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglossia)<sup>1</sup>, and each document has its own language declaration using `\setmainlanguage{}` (in my case, mostly to Turkish). **Is there some way to retrieve what language has been set and conditional output different strings based on which language is the document default?**

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Actually for some reason my style file *also* has `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}`, which seems to be should be redundant and potentially a conflict with polyglossia; maybe I should sort out why that got in there while I'm messing with this!</sub>

Comment: Both `babel` and `polyglossia` have `\languagename` which holds the currently active language name. And the `translations` package offers `\ifcurrentbaselanguage{<lang>}{<true>}{<false>}` for tests

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`polyglossia` stores the main language name in the macro `\xpg@main@language`, so it's easy to achieve what you want.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{turkish}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mainlanguage}{\xpg@main@language}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This document is written in \mainlanguage.

\IfStrEq{\mainlanguage}{turkish}{Yes, it's Turkish!}{No, it's not Turkish!}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As a side note, don't use `babel` if you're using `polyglossia` already...

Comment: In modern times, you can safely use `babel` with the new engines. But using `babel` *and* `polyglossia` is bad indeed.

Comment: Both `babel` and `polyglossia` have `\languagename` which holds the currently active language name. No need for `\xpg@main@language`

Comment: @clemens as you say, `\languagename` holds the "currently active" language, not the "main" language as requested by the OP...

Comment: But the OP says every of his documents has only one language so I don't see the difference here (although, I'm not sure `\languagename` can be trusted before begin document...)

Comment: @clemens Actually it's pretty useful to know both options because my documents are _not_ exclusively one language are the other, both directions have bits from other languages.

Comment: In babel, this macro is named `\bbl@main@language`.